# Mongoose: Adding Attributes to Nested Objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm currently using AngularJS, and the backend is using NodeJS and Express. I use Mongoose to access the database. I'm trying to figure how to add attributes to nested objects and I can't for the life of me find out how to do it anywhere on the web.

My Schema looks like this:

```
{
id: {
    type: String
},
involved: {
    type: String
},
lastMsgRead: Object

}
```

lastMsgRead will look something like this:

```
{
    user1: "somestringblahblah",
    user2: "someotherstring",
}
```

and so on.
My question is, how would I update lastMsgRead with Mongoose to add another attribute to it, such as adding user3 so it now looks like:

```
{
    user1: "somestringblahblah",
    user2: "someotherstring",
    user3: "anotherstring"
}
```

The entire document would like this after the update:

```
{
    id: "string",
    involved: "string",
    lastMsgRead: {
        user1: "somestringblahblah",
        user2: "someotherstring",
        user3: "anotherstring"
    }

}
```

Edit:
After I add the attribute, how would I then update it in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .dot notation to update in nested object

```
db.collection.update(
  { },
  { "$set": { "lastMsgRead.user3": "anotherstring" } }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

in mongoose 5.1.0 and up you can approach this with the [MongooseMap](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#maps).
You can define it in the schema as followed:

```
{
  id: {
    type: String
  },
  involved: {
    type: String
  },
  lastMsgRead: {
     type: Map,
     of: String
  }
}
```

you can then add a new value by `.set(key, value)`

```
myDoc.lastMsgRead.set(key, value)
```

and get a value by `.get(key)`

```
myDoc.lastMsgRead.get(key)
```